# Let's encrypt not working on last webmin 1.94 centos 8

Tags: python, centos, certbot, webmin

Unfortunately, Let's Encrypt cannot be used on your system : Neither the Let's Encrypt client command certbot or the python command were found on your system.

I installed certbot but i have this error message certbot seems installed  :

```
yum install certbot
En attente de la fin d’exécution du processus ayant l’identifiant (pid) 12890.
Erreur : 
 Problème: package certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch requires python3-certbot = 1.3.0-3.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3-mock needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(mock) needed by python3-certbot-1.3.0-3.el8.noarch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package python3-mock is provided by PowerTools repo.

Enable it via:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

Now your **yum update** should work fine.